# JavaScript algorithm for sorting an array in object by several criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object

I'm trying to write an algorithm that sorts this table by an average value from the each column grouped by the first column(name) so the table display only a rows with the most common values.For example this is the current table:

[image: unsorted table]

and after sorting should look like this:

[image: sorted table]

So this is the array I'm trying to sort and show only the most common table values:

```
            var testArray = [
            {
                "testName": "10b1",
                "SG": 1.010,
                "pH":6,
                "LEU": "NEG",
                "NIT": "NEG",
                "PRO": "NEG",
                "GLU": "NORM",
                "KET": "NEG",
                "UBG": "NORM",
                "BIL": "NEG",
                "Hb": "NEG"

            },
            {
                "testName": "10b1",
                "SG": 1.010,
                "pH":6,
                "LEU": "NEG",
                "NIT": "NEG",
                "PRO": "NEG",
                "GLU": "NORM",
                "KET": "NEG",
                "UBG": "NORM",
                "BIL": "NEG",
                "Hb": "NEG"
            },
            {
                "testName": "10b1",
                "SG": 1.010,
                "pH":6,
                "LEU": "NEG",
                "NIT": "NEG",
                "PRO": "NEG",
                "GLU": "NORM",
                "KET": "NEG",
                "UBG": "NORM",
                "BIL": "NEG",
                "Hb": "NEG"
            },
            {
                "testName": "10b1",
                "SG": 1.010,
                "pH":6,
                "LEU": "NEG",
                "NIT": "NEG",
                "PRO": "NEG",
                "GLU": "NORM",
                "KET": "NEG",
                "UBG": "NORM",
                "BIL": "NEG",
                "Hb": "NEG"
            },
            {
                "testName": "10b1",
                "SG": 1.010,
                "pH":6,
                "LEU": "NEG",
                "NIT": "NEG",
                "PRO": "NEG",
                "GLU": "NORM",
                "KET": "NEG",
                "UBG": "NORM",
                "BIL": "NEG",
                "Hb": "NEG"
            },
            {
                "testName": "10b1.5",
                "SG": 1.010,
                "pH":6,
                "LEU": "NEG",
                "NIT": "NEG",
                "PRO": "NEG",
                "GLU": 50,
                "KET": "NEG",
                "UBG": "NORM",
                "BIL": "NEG",
                "Hb": 50
            },
            {

                "testName": "10b1.5",
                "SG": 1.010,
                "pH":6,
                "LEU": "NEG",
                "NIT": "NEG",
                "PRO": "NEG",
                "GLU": 50,
                "KET": "NEG",
                "UBG": "NORM",
                "BIL": "NEG",
                "Hb": 50
            },
            {
                "testName": "10b1.5",
                "SG": 1.010,
                "pH":6,
                "LEU": "NEG",
                "NIT": "NEG",
                "PRO": "NEG",
                "GLU": 50,
                "KET": "NEG",
                "UBG": "NORM",
                "BIL": "NEG",
                "Hb": 50
            }
        ];
```

I tried to use this algorithm but the result that returns me is far from the expected result:

```
  var mf = 1;
        var m = 0;
        var item;
        var count = 1;
        for(let k = 0; k < testArray.length; k++){
            for(let v = 0; v < testArray[k].values.length; v++){
                 current = 1;
                for(j = v; j <= testArray[k].values.length; j++){
                    if(testArray[k].values[v] == testArray[k].values[j]){
                        m++;
                    }

                    if(mf < m){
                        mf=m;
                        item = testArray[k].values[v];
                        testArray[k].values = [];
                    }
                }
                    testArray[k].values[v] = item;

            }

        }
```

I would be grateful if someone can give some sample algorithm or solution to the problem :)

Comment: Why does the output have 2 rows if you want to get *"only the most common table values*" from each column?

Comment: Also, please don't upload [images of your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3082296). The image of your array cannot be copied to create an answer and images harder to read than text. Please post the actual code **as text** to create a [mcve].

Comment: I would like to display the most common values in the table grouped by name so for each name should display most common value, and the table currently has two names: "10b1", "10b1.5". So for each name I have to get the most common values.

Comment: You are right about the photo of the array  @adiga I'm really sorry about the image.. so I edited my question and set the current array, which is a valid JSON and can be used to write an example solution now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the array and create a nested object to group the array based on on name and then by key and finally by the value for each key. Then loop through the [**`entries`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of this `counts` nested obj and create an object based on the [*mode*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)) of values for each key

This is what the `counts` object looks like:

```js
{
    "10b1": {
        "SG": {
            "1.01": 5
        },
        "pH": {
            "6": 5
        },
        "LEU": {
            "NEG": 5
        },
        "NIT": {
            "NEG": 5
        },
        "PRO": {
            "NEG": 5
        },
        "GLU": {
            "NORM": 5
        },
        "KET": {
            "NEG": 5
        },
        "UBG": {
            "NORM": 5
        },
        "BIL": {
            "NEG": 5
        },
        "Hb": {
            "10": 3,
            "NEG": 2
        }
    },
    "10b1.5": {
        "SG": {
            "1.01": 3
        },
        "pH": {
            "6": 3
        },
        "LEU": {
            "NEG": 3
        },
        "NIT": {
            "NEG": 3
        },
        "PRO": {
            "NEG": 3
        },
        "GLU": {
            "50": 3
        },
        "KET": {
            "NEG": 3
        },
        "UBG": {
            "NORM": 3
        },
        "BIL": {
            "NEG": 3
        },
        "Hb": {
            "50": 3
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a working snippet:

`{ testName, ...rest }` in the [**`reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) parameter is for [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) each object to a separate `testName` and remaining properties to a `rest` object

```js
var array=[{testName:"10b1",SG:1.01,pH:6,LEU:"NEG",NIT:"NEG",PRO:"NEG",GLU:"NORM",KET:"NEG",UBG:"NORM",BIL:"NEG",Hb:"NEG"},{testName:"10b1",SG:1.01,pH:6,LEU:"NEG",NIT:"NEG",PRO:"NEG",GLU:"NORM",KET:"NEG",UBG:"NORM",BIL:"NEG",Hb:"10"},{testName:"10b1",SG:1.01,pH:6,LEU:"NEG",NIT:"NEG",PRO:"NEG",GLU:"NORM",KET:"NEG",UBG:"NORM",BIL:"NEG",Hb:"NEG"},{testName:"10b1",SG:1.01,pH:6,LEU:"NEG",NIT:"NEG",PRO:"NEG",GLU:"NORM",KET:"NEG",UBG:"NORM",BIL:"NEG",Hb:"10"},{testName:"10b1",SG:1.01,pH:6,LEU:"NEG",NIT:"NEG",PRO:"NEG",GLU:"NORM",KET:"NEG",UBG:"NORM",BIL:"NEG",Hb:"10"},{testName:"10b1.5",SG:1.01,pH:6,LEU:"NEG",NIT:"NEG",PRO:"NEG",GLU:50,KET:"NEG",UBG:"NORM",BIL:"NEG",Hb:50},{testName:"10b1.5",SG:1.01,pH:6,LEU:"NEG",NIT:"NEG",PRO:"NEG",GLU:50,KET:"NEG",UBG:"NORM",BIL:"NEG",Hb:50},{testName:"10b1.5",SG:1.01,pH:6,LEU:"NEG",NIT:"NEG",PRO:"NEG",GLU:50,KET:"NEG",UBG:"NORM",BIL:"NEG",Hb:50}];

const counts = array.reduce((acc, { testName, ...rest }) => {
   if(!acc[testName]) acc[testName] = {};

   let nested = acc[testName];
   
   Object.entries(rest).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if(!nested[key]) nested[key] = {}
    
    nested[key][value] = nested[key][value] + 1 || 1;
  })
  
  return acc
},{})

const output = Object.entries(counts).map(([testName, count]) => {
  const obj = { testName };
  
  Object.entries(count).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    const mode = Object.keys(v).sort((a, b) => v[b] - v[a])[0];
    obj[k] = mode;
  }, {})
  
  return obj
})

console.log(output)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

(None of the keys had more than one unique `value`. So, for the `10b1` name's `Hb` property, I have used: `"NEG", "10", "NEG", "10", "10"` values -- same as the image for demonstration)

Comment: Thanks @adiga :), It's work like a charm. Is there any way to return the array ordered, because it is out of order.now?

Comment: @jorobash what do you mean by order? It's currently shows `10b1` first and then `10b1.5`? Because that's the order in the original array

Comment: Yes the order of the names is correct, what I mean is when I test the code in the browser It's work, but the order of the "SG", "pH", "LEU", "NIT", "PRO" ...... etc is shuffle.Returns them this way:  `0: {…}
​​
BIL: "NEG"
​​
GLU: "NORM"
​​
Hb: "10"
​​
KET: "NEG"
​​
LEU: "NEG"
​​
NIT: "NEG"
​​
PRO: "NEG"
​​
SG: "1.01"
​​
UBG: "NORM"
​​
pH: "6"
​​
testName: "10b1"
​
​
1: {…}
​​
BIL: "NEG"
​​
GLU: "50"
​​
Hb: "50"
​​
KET: "NEG"
​​
LEU: "NEG"
​​
NIT: "NEG"
​​
PRO: "NEG"
​​
SG: "1.01"
​​
UBG: "NORM"
​​
pH: "6"
​​
testName: "
10b1.5"
​​`

Comment: @jorobash Not sure what you're asking here. In the example I have provided, in the input array, the objects have keys in the order of `"SG", "pH", "LEU", "NIT", "PRO", "GLU", "KET", "UBG", "BIL", "Hb"`. Same order is being maintained in the output's objects order. This is true at least for ES6 anyway: [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795)

Comment: Thanks @adiga you really help me!

Comment: @jorobash you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the grey checkmark on the left of the answer